# SQL: Concat columns into datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a date into char(8) in the form *yyyy-mm*.

I used *substring* function to extract **year** and **month** from that.

Now I'd like to *concat* these into a *datetime* of the form **yyyy-mm-01**.

I tried with

```
**CAST(CONCAT(01,cc.month,cc.year) as date) as ref_date**
```

but I think it is having problem with the **01**.

Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, am using SSMS 18

Comment: Dates aren't text and have no format. If you have a `char(8)` you have no dates.

Comment: The version of SSMS is somewhat irrelevant; SSMS 18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019 (that's 6.5 different versions)

Comment: More on topic, I don't think any combination of DMY setting and data type supports implicit conversion of `ddMMyyyy` to a date and time data time in SQL Server. Why *that* format? Why not an unambiguous one like `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: In any case, `cast(monthField + '-01' as date)` should work. ` yyyy-mm` isn't a date, it's a string specifying a period of 1 month. You can simply append `-01` to it to get a string representing the start of month in `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO8601) form. SQL Server can parse this into a date unambiguously. `select cast('2023-06' + '-01' as date)` works

Comment: select concat(year, right('0' + cast(month as varchar(2)), 2), '01') maybe.

Comment: `it is having problem with the 01.` no, the problem is you're trying to append the number 1, with parts in the *opposite* order from what you described. Your code produces `1062023`. `01` is a number, not a string

Comment: @siggemannen it's better to not use the parts at all, as the original string is already in `YYYY-MM` form. All that's needed is to append `-01` to the string to get an ISO8601 date

Comment: As a note, even if you did create the sting `'01062023'` it still wouldn't work; that would be parsed as the 23rd day of the 20th month of the year 0106.

Comment: `datefromparts(left(cc,4),right(cc,2),1)` and then convert/format this date as desired

Comment: @Roberto92 why? You don't have to split anything in the first place. You can get the value you want if you just append `'-01'` to the original string

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (
    id INT,
    date_column CHAR(8)
)

-- Insert sample data
INSERT INTO SampleTable (id, date_column)
VALUES 
    (1, '2022-01'),
    (2, '2022-02'),
    (3, '2022-03')

-- Query to concatenate year and month into a datetime value
SELECT 
    id,
    date_column,
    TRY_CONVERT(DATE, date_column + '-01') AS ref_date
FROM SampleTable
```

| id | date_column | ref_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-02 | 2022-02-01 |
| 3 | 2022-03 | 2022-03-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XfhICmjI)

Answer (score -1):

Much more efficient :

```
EOMONTH(CONVERT(DATE, cc.month + '-01', 121)) AS DATE_END,     CONVERT(DATE, cc.month + '-01', 121) AS DATE_START
```